# Is there multipath inside a shield box?

Tags: rf, reflection, shield

Since metal surfaces reflect EM waves, if I put a transmitting antenna inside a shield box will the transmitted RF signal scatter everywhere inside the box?

Comment: "scatter" is not the right word here ("scattering" has a specific meaning in EM theory, and it's not what happens here). They will resonate, depending on the geometry of the box relative to the wavelength. "Reflecting" is kind of  a macroscopic view of things, which only applies if wavelengths are much smaller than objects, and for "antenna in box" this probably is not the case? We don't know - you tell us nothing about the size of box and the frequency of your waves.

Comment: Also note that, because no radiation escapes from the box (assumption), there is no radiation resistance, and it all reflects back to the antenna, vastly altering its port impedance.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I don't agree with your scattering terminology. For example, Mie scattering off a sphere applies whether the sphere is smaller or larger than the wavelength. I would argue scattering is typically thought of as a far field phenomenon. In this case, a shielded box is a near field phenomenon and can be far more complex. For example, a shield whose width is on the same order of the wavelength can act as a waveguide, actually reducing isolation between components in the shield!

Comment: Regarding the actual question, this is how coaxial to waveguide transitions are made. A monopole antenna, for example, is inserted into a waveguide at particular point that maximizes coupling from the antenna to a waveguide mode. When designing waveguide resonators, sometimes the coupling is backed off so as not to load the resonator too much. Small loop antennas are also sometimes used as a transition. In any case, this mode coupling is a near field phenomenon (for waveguide-sized boxes)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. If the size of the metal box is much bigger compared to the wavelength of the radio signal (e.g. a computer or radio transmitter at 1 GHz), the signals emitted from the shielded circuit would keep reflecting all over the place inside the box. A single impulse reflects almost endlessly (it eventually dissipates due to resistve loss).

Reflection also turns the box into a cavity resonator, with standing waves at nodes with very high electric or magnetic field strength. In fact, room-sized metal boxes known as [electromagnetic reverberation chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_reverberation_chamber) are used to deliberately create an environment with very high field strength for electromagnetic immunity testing.

> 6.17 CAVITY RESONANCE
>
> Energy enclosed in a metal box will bounce off the box's interior walls. If electromagnetic energy gets into the box (from a source inside the box or from leakage of external energy into the box), the box will act as a cavity resonator. As the energy bounces (reflects) from one surface to another, it produces standing waves within the box, depending on the size and shape of the enclosure. At
> frequencies that correspond to the box resonance, these standing waves will produce high field strengths at some points within the enclosure and nulls at other points. For a cubical box, the lowest resonant frequency is (White, 1975):
>
> \$ f_{\text{MHz}} = \frac{212}{l} \$ (6.41)
>
> where \$ f_{\text{MHz}} \$ is the resonant frequency in megahertz and \$ l  \$ is the length of one side of the box in meters. Additional resonances will occur at frequencies above this. In general, a rectangular box will have multiple resonant frequencies located at (White, 1975):
>
> \$ f_{\text{MHz}} = 150 \cdot \sqrt{(\frac{k}{l})^2 + (\frac{m}{h})^2 + (\frac{n}{w})^2} \$ (6.42)
>
> where l, h, and w are the length, height, and width (in meters) of the box respectively, and k, m, and n are positive integers (0, 1, 2, 3, etc.) that represent the various possible modes of propagation. No more than one of the integers can be zero at any one time. For example, k=1, m=0, and n=12 represents the lowest resonant frequency for the TE101 mode of propagation. The resonant frequency that corresponds to the lowest order of propagation will have two of the integers (k, m, or n) equal to one and the other integer equal to zero.
>
> Equation 6-42 can be applied to a cubical box by letting w = h = l. For the case of the lowest resonant frequency the integers k, m, and n will be equal to 1, 1, and 0 in any sequence. If the above conditions are substituted into Eq. 6-42, then it reduces to Eq. 6-41.
>
> - Henry W. Ott - Electromagnetic Compatibility Engineering

As a result, while shielding is the go-to solution for protecting a circuit board from receiving or generating interference, but mindlessly putting a circuit board into a metal chassis for "shielding" can sometimes seriously degrade its performance in an unpredictable manner. In case you're unlucky, sometimes a component may reside at a point with very high field strength, or sometimes harmful interference is reflected right back into into your circuit.

> Note that the standing wave has the characteristic such that the E and H fields are 90o
> out of phase with each other. The impedance
> will therefore fluctuate wildly across the cavity causing unknown (usually bad) effects on
> circuitry including the introduction of instability to active devices. The H field also is at
> its maximum at the wall of the cavity, which
> may cause the shielding effectiveness to deteriorate at the resonant frequencies. Often what
> is perceived as a shielding issue requiring
> attention to shielding materials is actually a
> cavity resonance issue.
> Relocating a particular circuit element to
> a different position in the cavity can often
> fix the problem. Intelligent positioning of
> posts or other objects to disrupt the standing
> wave can also be helpful, but both these
> methods can involve an investment in engineering design time and possible manufacturing delays.
>
> - [Dampening cavity resonance using absorber material](https://www.laird.com/sites/default/files/2019-01/Dampening%20Cavity%20Resonance%20Using%20Absorber%20Material%20White%20Paper.pdf), RF Design Magazine

There are two solutions to this problem. First, calculations, simulations or measurements can be done to ensure the shield does not interact in a harmful manner with the circuit. For example, if the operating frequency of your circuit (including high-order harmonics) is far below the lowest resonance frequency of the box, there's little to worry.

Another solution is using RF absorptive materials around the metal shield, usually a layer of "EMI foam". These materials behave like resistors to electromagnetic waves, creating losses and greatly reduces the reflected energy - much like a termination resistor at the end a transmission line. This way, instead of creating a miniature [electromagnetic reverberation chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_reverberation_chamber), we create an [anechoic chamber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anechoic_chamber) instead.

Further, "antenna in a metal box" is not just an unwanted side effect. It also has useful and important applications: If we put "antenna in metal tubes", it becomes a type of transmission line of electromagnetic waves, known as waveguides.

[image: The magnetic field in the waveguide.]

Source: [The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume II, Chapter 24 - Waveguide](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_24.html)

Roughly speaking, one way to understand waveguide propagation is imagining waves bouncing back and forth between the metal walls, not unlike optical fibers - although the actual physical detail is fairly complex, as the "bouncing wave" interpretation must be understood as a superposition of two planes waves, not one. A cavity resonator or waveguide also has many different modes of resonance or propagation.

[image: The waveguide field can be viewed as the superposition of two trains of plane waves.]

Source: [The Feynman Lectures on Physics, Volume II, Chapter 24 - Waveguide](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_24.html)